# Minimum Continuous Sub-sequence with two Lists

Tags: java, algorithm, oop

TargetList and AvailableTagsList are two lists of string. TargetList will contain Distinct string objects.

```
Input:
TargetList = {"cat", "dog"};
AvailableTagsList = {"cat", "test", "dog", "get", "spain", "south"};
Output: [0, 2] //'cat' in position 0; 'dog' in position 2


Input:
TargetList = {"east", "in", "south"};
AvailableTagsList = {"east", "test", "east", "in", "east", "get", "spain", "south"};
Output: [2, 7] //'east' in position 2; 'in' in position 3; 
              //'south' in position 6 (east in position 4 is not outputted as it is coming after 'in')

Input:
TargetList = {"east", "in", "south"};
AvailableTagsList = {"east", "test", "south"};
Output: [0] //'in' not present in availableTagsList
```

I store the positions of words where they appear in the `AvailableTags` into a `listMap`.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> listMap = new HashMap<>();
int counter = 0;
for(String availableItem : AvailableTagsList) 
{
    if(listMap.containsKey(availableItem))
        listMap.get(availableItem).add(counter);
    else 
    {
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(counter);
        listMap.put(availableItem, temp);
    }
    counter++;
}
```

And I add all element list in `listMap` to a `resultList`.

```
listMap will be like 
"east" - [0,2,4] 
"in" - [3] 
"south" - [7] 

resultList will have like [0,2,4,3,7]
```

What I can't wrap my head around with is, using this `resultList` how do I display the minimum subsequence in the `AvailableTagsList`? Am I using the right approach? How is my progress so far? Are there any other alternative approaches to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the optimum solution for this problem but according to your idea

- Get the position of each word from TargetList in the
  AvailableTagsList (Note that they will be sorted) for example if my
  target list and available list are : TargetList = {"east", "in",
  "south"} AvailableTagsList = {"east", "test", "east", "in", "east",
  "get", "spain", "south"} So after this step I would have  east :
  0,2,4 in : 3 south: 7
- Now: I know that I can have 3 possible start right? for the first
  position of my start word p0, can I find a position p1 for word
  (i+1) such that p1 > p0 ?? if yes, can I have a position p2 for
  word(i+2) such that p2 > p1 and so on till I find all my target list.
  How can I do that ? if I know position p1 , I need to  find the
  first p2  such that p2 > p1 ? Can I use binary search to do that ?
  yes because all the arrays are sorted . So here is the code

```
public class MinimumCtsSubsequence {

    static String[] words, tags;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        words = new String[] { "east", "in", "south" };
        tags = new String[] { "east", "test", "east", "in", "east", "get", "spain", "south" };
        ArrayList<Integer> ans = minSubSequence();
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.print(ans.get(i) + " ");
        }

    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> minSubSequence() {
        ArrayList<Integer>[] occur = new ArrayList[words.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i)
            occur[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> indices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
            indices.put(words[i], i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
            String tag = tags[i];
            if (indices.containsKey(tag)) {
                int wordI = indices.get(tag);
                occur[wordI].add(i);
            }
        }
        // till now comp is o(n)
        // loop throught all the starts that we have
        int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int s1 = 0, e1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < occur[0].size(); ++i) {
            int start = occur[0].get(i);
            boolean poss = true;
            int next = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < words.length; ++j) {
                next = getNextGreater(start, occur[j]);
                if (next == -1) {
                    poss = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (poss && ans > next - start) {
                s1 = start;
                e1 = next;
                ans = next - start;
            }

        }
        ArrayList<Integer> solu = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (ans == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            solu.add(0);
            return solu;
        }

        solu.add(s1);
        solu.add(e1);

        return solu;
    }

    static int getNextGreater(int x, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.size() - 1;
        int ans = -1;
        while (start < end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (arr.get(mid) <= x) {// go right
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                ans = arr.get(mid);
                end = mid;
            }

        }
        if (start == end && arr.get(start) > x)
            return arr.get(start);
        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a tendency to see things as Graph problems, so I would look at this as a graph problem*. After the step of making a list map as you have already done, you can construct a graph that you will end up finding a shortest path with.

- Make one node S that will be the source.
- Make one node D that will be the destination.
- Add nodes for each occurrence of the words that you care about, ensuring that you know which position they are for.
- Add edges from source to each occurrence with a weight of 0 (since you can start at any of these).

  - for your example these would be:

    - east0
    - east2
    - east4
    - in3
    - south7
- Add edges from each of the final words to dest with a weight of 0 (again, you can finish at any of these)
- For each pair of adjacent words in your target list (w1,w2) [e.g. (east, in), (in, south) from your example]:

  - Add an edge from each node for w1 to each node for w2, where the node for w2 has a position greater than the node from w1, with weight equal to the difference in their positions. **
  - With your example, these edges:

    - east0 -> in3, weight 3
    - east2 -> in3, weight 1
    - in3 -> south7, weight 4
- now that you have the graph find the shortest path from S to D with any method for doing that (e.g. Djikstra's algorithm)

Because you wanted the positions to start and finish, you will need to keep track of which nodes form the shortest path, and what positions they were from so that you can return these nodes' positions. This is a very typical augmentation of shortest path algorithms and there are likely examples and guidance that can be found somewhere on the internet.

---

*I don't advocate that this is necessarily a good choice, or the fastest, or simplest choice, but it will work.

** There's an an optimisation here where you make each w1 node have an edge to the next w1 node, and each w1 node only connects to the nearest w2 node that occurs with a position greater than it.

---

Having a few hours to think about this, I'm pretty sure that you can do it in O(n) time and space like this (using the optimised graph, and constructing it carefully from the input). So it's at least not horribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to not merge those lists as presented on the initial question.

You must realise that the range will only ever get affected by the indexes for the first and last tag. What happens in between will not really affect the range (if it does exist).

Having said that, there are two constraints that need to hold for any valid solution.

If each tag has a list of indexes, if you move from each tag in order from the left:

- An index found in 'current tag' MUST have a greater index in 'next tag' and so on until we reach the end of tags.

If you move from the right:

- An index found in 'current tag' MUST have a lesser index in 'previous tag' and so until we reach the beginning of tags.

Basically, you try to shrink from both ends.

If at any point you fail to satisfy these constraints then you know there's no valid solution.

I don't know if this the optimal solution or approach. But it would work.